how to handle Flutter Rest API call error with Dio
When working with Nested json object or Complex json using Dio. Give me this error

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

My question is Null Safety is the first thing thats i am doing but if have any unconsciously required field with null from server in that time only give me this error, But Nested or Complex Json which Model variable is getting null it' s hard to find manually. But when working with native Android and call API with Retrofit . Retrofit gives me specific point (Model variable) getting null.But flutter Dio does not give.
Have any solution for this problem like When Network Data and local Model type will be mismatch, Show me error with which data Model variable has got null. Please help me I am facing major issue with this problem.
getting Error with Network call flutter Dio

first of all, I'm sorry for the error you encountered. It's an annoying issue; 'as far as I know,' there is no way other than finding it manually. Maybe using breakpoints could be helpful. Or, if your models are not too complex, you could try resolving the issue by making the fields that might be null nullable (String?).
(edited)
Or:
void logNullValues(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  data.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value == null) {
      debugPrint('The value for "$key" is null.');
    }
  });
}


Thank you for your response , but where i am put this function give me details Brother @Altay

You can use this in your fromJson() or similar function to log the operation now. @MdEusufUddin

But this is give me also nullable key. I need only specific key which for generate problem

I want another way like flutter build in any one way

It's not a suitable way cause large and complex json with loop is not a suitable thing

I'm sorry for the late response, I was traveling. I can explain it like this: Here, it expects a String (No String?) value, so this is a notification to stop the program if null occurs, thanks to Dart's null-safety update. With the function I provided above, you can add these values automatically and see which key is causing the error. If you are manually adding smaller data (my recommendation is that it usually doesn't matter if it's small, it should be functional), you can find which value is null and if the key is a String this way.

Its oke to have errors while playing with json structures . use this package to generate model just refer any video or documentation of json
serializable before using it . https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable try to also learn about null operators that can help. refer https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety for null safety.
While using a json or just take map<string, string> in dart for example if we take a value from the map using a key we need check that if it's null because the value which we get if the key is not present in the map we will get null. It is as similar in json while it's nested json . It may have list of jsons objects where some have a key but some of them may change so the best approach is to use json serializable or to use nullable string "String?"

As my question was when nested model class fromjson to parse response with our exact model. Somehow give me error type is not a subtype of String means somehow String type variable get null, but Nested model which string is null . They dont specified , in that scenario what will i do.
